# How to schedule a function to certain date time or convert a function into Console App?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a Windows Forms app where I am trying to send SMS and Email messages using the company back-end.

Lets say I have N classes (SMS sender and Email sender are part of them), and all of these classes have Execute() function which calls the required back end service. What I want to do is, given that user filled the required areas (Mail template, receiver email etc.) the user will be selecting a date time to execute the given function.

I know that I can use a Timer but that consumes too many resources.

I know that I can use Windows scheduler but I think I have to convert my functions to .exe files and schedule them using Windows Task Scheduler but I cannot simply convert my project into Console App

How can I call my Execute() function at a given DateTime?

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: This will only work when the winforms app stays open all the time, 24*7. Your backend, assuming it is a 24*7 running background process, should create the timer. Or indeed use windows scheduler or a windows service on a server machine running 24*7.

Comment: *"I can use a Timer but that consumes too many resources."* -- So you want a solution that consumes less resources than a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? How many resources are too many?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias AFAIK Timer runs all the time in the background and I will have to check if the time has come manually, I want some kind of software interrupt to be fired at given DateTime which runs my function, not manual controls

Comment: @MitchWheat Thanks for your answer, I know about that but I might not have the authority to use 3rd party libraries after Log4J problems.

Comment: @PeterBons I cannot edit the back end since it is used by numerous teams and the servers are heavily loaded all the times (Sending and receiving thousands of messages per second). My application will be used for testing purposes within my team.

Comment: No, the `Timer` is a lightweight component. It doesn't run all the time. It runs only when the `Tick` event handler is invoked.

Comment: and, given a due date and the current data you can calculate the exact timespan needed to initialize the timer. But still, if the due date is a couple of hours or days in the future the desktop app needs to stay open all the time! Isn't that an issue?

Comment: Yes, why we are trying to automate these tests is they are usually done at 2-3AM, given that our shift ends at 6PM the PC needs to stay open for at least 10 hours. Thats an issue yes, but not as much as staying up until 3AM to do the tests and go for 5 hours of sleep.

Comment: As mentioned  @Mitch Wheat , you can also use the [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org)   framework. You can also use the [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)  framework.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, schedule should't be made on the client PC - what if someone closes the app / entire PC ? Sure you can create kind of service to handle this in background, but it's not solving pc power-off problem.

So, your webservice should be responsive for execution of scheule. Client app should send message to webservice like "at 8pm send message to ...".

In webservice you should use some kind of scheduler eg. Quartz.NET or Hangfire.
About your Log4J problems, Log4Net is not affected:
https://blogs.apache.org/security/entry/cve-2021-44228

If webservice you're sending message to isn't yours, then IMO Windows Service + scheduler can be a solution.. but only if the machine is running 24/7, otherwise there'll always be achance that some messages wont be send.